# When do Merry and Pippin find out that Frodo & Sam have gone to Mordor?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

When do Merry and Pippin find out about what happened to Frodo and Sam? Where were they, and who told them? Merry and Pippin were captured by Orcs after the Fellowship was broken at Parth Galen.

Maybe I've missed it but seems like this is not made clear. Gandalf finds out from Aragorn and his companions when they meet him in Fangorn but who tells Merry and Pippin?

Comment: In the film or the book?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the book, we do not see this scene, and it's not directly referred to, but they apparently learn it from Treebeard, who in turn bears it from Gandalf when Gandalf reaches Orthanc the evening after the Ents attacked Isengard:

> 'Treebeard was very thoughtful after Gandalf had gone. He had evidently learnt a lot in a short time and was digesting it.... Before he went, we got a little news out of him; and it did not cheer us up at all. But for the moment we thought more about you three than about *Frodo and Sam*, or about poor Boromir. '

(Pippin, in "The Two Towers", Chapter IX, "Flotsam and Jetsam")

Comment: It was most likely then. And if they had wanted the full story, they probably got it when Theoden, Gandalf and co came to Isengard after the battle of Helm's Deep. Aragorn, Legolas and Gimli could have explained more deeply.